# validation fails for greater than value string > int

Tags: php, validation, session

My validation is failing at my 'else if' statement. I have a string value of "24" for my variable `$_SESSION_PLAN_ID (post data)` and trying to compare it with value of `$plancompare` which `9 (not a string/DB data)`.
24 is greater than > 9
But my debug output `echo 'burrp 3';` is never hit.

```
                var_dump($_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID']);
                echo "</br>";
                if(!empty($_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID'])){
                        echo 'burrrp 1';
                        if($_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID'] >= 20 || $plancompare >= 20){
                                echo 'burrrp 2';
                                $_SESSION['SESS_DNSSEC'] = 1;
                        }else if($_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID'] > $plancompare){
                                echo 'burrrp 3';
                                echo '<br>';
                                $_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_BUY_CODE'] = $_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID'];
                        }
                }
                $_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID'] = $plancompare;
                var_dump($_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID']);
                echo "</br>";
                var_dump($_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_BUY_CODE']);
                echo "</br>";
                var_dump($_SESSION['SESS_DNSSEC']);
                session_write_close();
```

var_dump() output:

```
string(2) "24"
burrrp 1burrrp 2int(9)
int(0)
int(1)
```

How do I validate a string 24 to be greater than a int 9?

Comment: NIX please up-vote the answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your condition like below, you need to do compression between similar datatypes:-

```
if((int)$_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID'] >= 20 || $plancompare >= 20){
                                echo 'burrrp 2';
                                $_SESSION['SESS_DNSSEC'] = 1;
                        }else if((int)$_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID'] > $plancompare){
                                echo 'burrrp 3';
                                echo '<br>';
                                $_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_BUY_CODE'] = $_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID'];
                        }
```

Note:- change bothe variable value into integer and then compare. Thanks.

Comment: It still never validates when changing them to int  ->  string(2) "23"
burrrp 1burrrp 2int(9)
int(0)
int(1)

Comment: Let me know `$_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID']` is having string value 24 and `$plancompare` having integer value 9 . is it? check my edited answer

Comment: same thing setting just the string to int  ->  http://i.imgur.com/jLYN4EN.png   live shot   :/

Comment: hey you leave first if condition change. look that

Comment: @NIX numeric strings are automatically type-cast into integers for comparison. There's a problem in the logic of your conditions.

Comment: this st00pid site says 'i reached my limit'. no clue

Comment: you can do Some up-vote only per day only. you can do it next day no problem.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will automatically convert a numeric string into an integer for comparison, there's no need to separately type-cast them. Your code never gets to the third burp simply because your first condition always validates, because 24 will always be larger than 20 -- `$_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID'] >= 20` -- and therefore the `else` part is never evaluated. Also, your first `if` condition is `||` meaning `OR`, so if the first part is true, it doesn't matter if the second part is true or not. Use `&&` if both need to be true.

Another issue you probably have results from the line `$_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID'] = $plancompare;`, unless you're resetting your session between your debuggings. If you set them to the same value, then `$_SESSION['SESS_PLAN_ID'] > $plancompare` will always be false, because `9 > 9 == false`.